# Program breaks and I don't understand why

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

This is the latest piece of code I have written.  I'm trying to figure out several things.

Issue: I think I almost have it, but it is saying that every PIN is valid, which it isn't.  This means that the ValidatePIN proc is wrong, but I can't seem to figure it out.  Any suggestions?

Thanks much for your help!!!!!

```
; 32-bit assembly language template

; INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

INCLUDELIB C:\Irvine\Kernel32.lib
INCLUDELIB C:\Irvine\Irvine32.lib
INCLUDE C:\Irvine\Irvine32.inc

pbyte typedef ptr byte                          ; pointer to bytes

.data
VALID_PIN = 0
PIN_SIZE = 5
minVals byte 5,2,4,1,3                  ; globally visible
maxVals byte 9,5,8,4,6                  ; globally visible
samplePin_1 byte 6,3,4,4,3              ; valid PIN
samplePin_2 byte 5,2,3,2,4              ; digit 3 is invalid
samplePin_3 byte 5,2,4,5,3              ; digit 4 is invalid
samplePin_4 byte 1,3,4,4,3              ; digit 1 is invalid

ptr1 pbyte samplePin_1                          ; points to array samplePin_1
ptr2 pbyte samplePin_2                          ; points to array samplePin_2
ptr3 pbyte samplePin_3                          ; points to array samplePin_3
ptr4 pbyte samplePin_4                          ; points to array samplePin_4
ptr5 pbyte minVals                              ; points to array minVals
ptr6 pbyte maxVals                              ; points to array maxVals

ValidPINMsg byte "The PIN is valid     ", 0    ;
InvalidPINMsg byte "The PIN is invalid.  The invalid digit is     ", 0 ;

.code
main proc

mov eax,VALID_PIN                  ; 

mov edi,ptr5
mov ebp,ptr6

mov esi,ptr1
call ValidatePIN                   ; determine whether or not the PIN is valid
.IF eax == ecx
 mov edx,OFFSET ValidPINMsg
 call WriteString
 call WaitMsg
 call Crlf
.ELSE
 mov edx,OFFSET InvalidPINMsg
 call WriteString
 call WriteDec
 call WaitMsg
 call Crlf
.ENDIF

mov esi,ptr2
call ValidatePIN                   ; determine whether or not the PIN is valid                       
.IF eax == ecx
 mov edx,OFFSET ValidPINMsg
 call WriteString
 call WaitMsg
 call Crlf
.ELSE
 mov edx,OFFSET InvalidPINMsg
 call WriteString
 call WriteDec
 call WaitMsg
 call Crlf
.ENDIF

mov esi,ptr3
call ValidatePIN                   ; determine whether or not the PIN is valid                       
.IF eax == ecx
 mov edx,OFFSET ValidPINMsg
 call WaitMsg
 call Crlf
.ELSE
 mov edx,OFFSET InvalidPINMsg
 call WriteString
 call WriteDec
 call WaitMsg
 call Crlf
.ENDIF

mov esi,ptr4
call ValidatePIN                   ; determine whether or not the pin is valid                       
.IF eax == ecx
 mov edx,OFFSET ValidPINMsg
 call WriteString
 call WaitMsg
 call Crlf
.ELSE
 mov edx,OFFSET InvalidPINMsg
 call WriteString
 call WriteDec
 call WaitMsg
 call Crlf
.ENDIF

main endp

ValidatePIN PROC
 mov ecx,PIN_SIZE

 .REPEAT

.IF (esi < edi) || (esi > ebp)
    call L1
.ELSE
 add esi,1
 add edi,1
 add ebp,1
.ENDIF

dec ecx    

.UNTIL ecx == 0

L1: 
 mov eax,ecx
 ret

ret
ValidatePIN ENDP
END main
```

Comment: eip? that's just a register that points to the currently executing instruction. nothing in your code uses eip (other than indirectly, since it DOES change to exactly reflect your code's flow).

Comment: Yes, well, I fixed the issue of the "Break" by inserting a call L1, where L1: ret.  That still does not make the program run correctly though as I don't think the .WHILE, .IF, and .ELSE are executing correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue #1: You forgot `exit` at the end of `main` and `ret` at the end of `ValidatePIN`

Issue #2: `Irvine32.lib` has a [CRLF-function](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/source/irvinelib/crlf.htm). Insert `call CrLf`, where you wish to have a new line.

Issue #3: Typically a function returns a result in `EAX`. This value in `EAX` can be evaluated by the caller. In assembly you are free to return return other values in other registers. With `Irvine32.lib` you can [print the value of `EAX` decimal](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/source/irvinelib/writedec.htm)

There are other useful functions. Take a look at the [whole help for Irvine32.inc (with frameset)](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/)

**Addendum:**

There are further issues:

```
call ValidatePIN                   ; determine whether or not the PIN is valid
.IF eax == ecx
 mov edx,OFFSET ValidPINMsg
...
.ELSE
...
```

When should `EAX` become unequal to `ECX`? The last instruction of `ValidatePIN` is `mov eax,ecx`, so `EAX` and `ECX` are always equal at this point. You meant `.IF eax == 0`.

```
mov esi,ptr2
call ValidatePIN                   ; determine whether or not the PIN is valid
...
```

`EDI` and `EBP` were modified by the last procedures (`call ...`). You have to initialiaze them again.

```
.IF (esi < edi) || (esi > ebp)
...
```

`ESI`, `EDI` and `EBP` are here pointers (i.e. memory addresses) **not** values. To get the values you have to decorate the pointers with square brackets. But you can't directly compare memory with memory in x86-assembly. The next problem is to guarantee, that only a byte and not a dword will be compared. TL;DR:

```
mov al, byte ptr [esi]
.IF (al < [edi]) || (al > [ebp])
...
```

`AL` is the lowest byte of `EAX`. MASM recognizes now, that you want only process bytes.

```
call L1
```

A `call` will return. I guess you want to abort the loop at this point. Thus:

```
jmp L1
```

You won't like the number of the invalid digit. `ECX` (which determines the returning `EAX`) counts down in the loop: 5-4-3-2-1-0. To get a "count-up" you have to calculate `(6 - ECX)`, but leave ECX=0 unchanged. You can transform that term to `(-ECX + 6)`. So, change

```
.IF (al < [edi]) || (al > [ebp])
    jmp L1
.ELSE
...
```

to

```
.IF (al < [edi]) || (al > [ebp])
    neg ecx
    add ecx, 6
    jmp L1
.ELSE
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I am updating the code now, but the other issue I'm having is that ecx will not decrement like I'm telling it to in the ValidatePIN proc. Can you look at the updated code and see what I might be doing wrong?  Thank you again!

Comment: @user3727648: It's not a good idea to modify the question fundamentally. So my answer and the comments lost their reference. Take a look at my addendum. BTW: the `main` procedure still lacks an `exit`.

Comment: You're right.  I have the program working at the moment and it tells me that samplePin_1 is valid, while samplePin_2 through 4 are invalid, but the invalid digit is not correct.  Time to figure out why...

Comment: I get why the program is outputting that samplePin_2 invalid digit is 3, samplePin_3 invalid digit is 2 (even though correct invalid digit is 4), and samplePin_4 invalid digit is 5 (even though correct invalid digit is 1) and it is because of the value in ecx when the jum is made and because that is being moved into eax, which is being written to the console when WriteDec is called.  I'm having a mental-block though and can't seem to think of a solution.  I know you've helped me a great deal already, but can you pls make a suggestion without giving me the answer?

Comment: That was the answer lol.  The program outputs correctly now.  I appreciate your help and need to continue studying this chapter in order to further understand it.